# How to resize a bmp photo to be well printed

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a bmp photo. It is the photo of a signature. I am going to use the bmp photo for a pdf file. When I dynamically create the pdf file, the bmp file appears with its pixels visible.

What should I do to avoid the pixel problems for the photo which is used in the pdf files that are going to be printed ?

Regards bk

Comment: Are you creating the PDF from a Word document? What size (in pixels) is your BMP image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either convert the bitmap image to vector image (Maybe [this](http://vectormagic.com/home) could help) or you can increase resolution of the signature in Photoshop or GIMP or something similar, they are able to quite nicely smooth the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove some of the blockiness by creating new pixels and assigning their colours to be the average of the neighbouring pixels. Not sure which (if any) image manipulation programs do this though.

However, the image will still be horribly blurred.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to have a new signature photographed at a much higher resolution.  This way the pixels would not be visible, and the graphic would be of higher quality.

Answer (score 0):

A bitmap is just that. A map of bits.

You can't make them bigger than their original resolution and retain the same quality, because there's no higher resolution stored! No CSI-style "Enlarge. Enhance." behaviour is possible here :P

Answer (score 0):

open a word processor, insert the image, resize the image by dragging the borders to the size that suits you, take a screenshot, paste into paint, cut out the signature and save it.

now you have the signature ready to insert into any document you want, then print your PDF.

of course you can do the resizing with pretty much any image prozessor, but if you resize the signature in a text document you have a fair idea of its proportions.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put rasterized data in a scalable vector format. In English, you can't expand the signature in its current form because that data doesn't exist. The computer has to use an algorithm to blow it up, and when it does, you get the "pixelated" appearance.

The best way, as sYsinfo alluded to, would be to convert the image into a vector format. That's a fairly complicated task that usually has to be done by hand, though. You might want to just try capturing the signature into a larger image so there is more data to work with.